Check the need for composer install
I have a running project with some dependencies. I'm making some modifications, and I require a new package. So on my dev platform I run composer require x/x and the package gets installed.
Now I'm pushing this to prod. So, I already have my vendor/ folder with all my dependencies installed, but I don't have yet the new package and its content. I know that if I run composer install, I will install the new package and nothing else, but is there a way to know (a command) that there actually is a new package to install?
This issue presented itself because I would like to not have to run composer install every time in my CI/CD, but only when it is needed. Is there a way for that?
Otherwise, I guess I will have to check for file modifications on composer.json/composer.lock.
Output of composer diagnose:
root@34ac8973c327:/app# composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking composer.lock: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.39.5
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking Composer version: OK
Checking Composer and its dependencies for vulnerabilities: OK
Composer version: 2.8.3
PHP version: 8.3.14
PHP binary path: /usr/local/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
curl version: 7.88.1 libz 1.2.13 ssl OpenSSL/3.0.15
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available

I already tried composer status but it only show if you modified a file inside vendor/ (checks the integrity of the packages), not if all packages are installed properly regarding composer.json / composer.lock.

Can't you just check if the composer.lock has changed?

If everything is working properly, it looks good. Usually, there's no need to run composer install on the production system

"because I would like to not have to run composer install every time in my CI/CD, but only when it is needed" - why not? Did you put the vendor folder in your repository?

The best way is to just run composer install as it will compare the composer.lock file against the currently installed libraries. Nothing heavy should happen during this process as no dependency resolution needs to happen, only reading composer.lock and some metadata from installed libraries. Why do you think you need to work around this?

I have some scripts, that take some time to be executed, this is why I wanted to run composer install only if its needed (even if there is no packages to install, it will run the scripts). Really my question is for deep optimization purposes and curiosity but there's no life at stakes here.

"I have some scripts, that take some time to be executed" - how does this related to composer install?

Because when I run composer install, after the new packages are installed, those scripts are run too, by composer. I have a scripts section in my composer.json.

If you don't want to run these scripts, use composer install --no-scripts

I've kept on looking after posting this question, and I think I got my answer.
I've looked at the logs of running composer install, which looks like this (when there is nothing to do) :
root@f431aaa99341:/app# composer install --dry-run -vvv
Running 2.8.3 (2024-11-17 13:13:04) with PHP 8.3.14 on Linux / 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Reading ./composer.json (/app/composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (/app/composer.json)
Checked CA file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/app): 'git' 'branch' '-a' '--no-color' '--no-abbrev' '-v'
Executing async command (/app): 'git' 'rev-list' 'main..7-api-user'
Executing async command (/app): 'git' 'rev-list' 'remotes/origin/main..7-api-user'
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /config/composer/composer.json

Reading /app/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Symfony\Component\Runtime\Internal\ComposerPlugin (from symfony/runtime)
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex (from symfony/flex)
Reading ./composer.lock (/app/composer.lock)
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Reading ./composer.lock (/app/composer.lock)
> pre-pool-create: Symfony\Flex\Flex->truncatePackages
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-flex-main-index.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-contrib-flex-main-index.json from cache
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
> pre-pool-create: Symfony\Flex\Flex->truncatePackages
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-flex-main-index.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-contrib-flex-main-index.json from cache
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
Built pool.
Generating rules
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
> pre-operations-exec: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordOperations
Nothing to install, update or remove
93 packages you are using are looking for funding.
> pre-operations-exec: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordOperations
Nothing to install, update or remove
93 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Then I got on Github to look at Composer source code, and after a brief reading, it turns out that the "differential" made when we run composer install (in order to install only the packages taht need to be) is part of the code, but there's no direct command associated.
Based on a quick reading, it performs a differential of your composer needs with an installed.json file.
In the end, I do believe there is no composer command that suits my exact need at this moment.
